# Faulty input behavior with conditionals

Tags: python

I am trying to make it reset if the user doesn't type `m` or `f` for the gender.

```
GenderSelect = input("Are they male or female?(m/f)\n")

os.system("clear")
gerror = 1
while gerror == 1:
    os.system("cls")
    print("Create a name for your new friend.\n" + NameCreate + "\nHow old are they?\n" + str(AgeSelect))
    input("Are they male or female?(m/f)\n")
    if (GenderSelect.lower() == "m"):
        print("Name: " + NameCreate + "\nAge: " + str(AgeSelect) + "\nGender: Male\n")
        gerror = 0
    if (GenderSelect.lower() == "f"):
        print("Name: " + NameCreate + "\nAge: " + str(AgeSelect) + "\nGender: Female\n")
        gerror = 0
    if (not(GenderSelect.lower() == "f" GenderSelect.lower() == "m")):
        gerror = 1

Confirm = input("Is this correct?\n")

if(Confirm.lower() == "y" or Confirm.lower() == "yes"):
```

When I type `f` or `m` it resets but if I type anything else it doesn't.

Comment: Your title should reflect what the question is asking. This isn't really a question either.

Comment: The last `if` makes no much sense. Review the syntax

Comment: Consider using `if/elif/else`. Also you should input `genderselect` _inside_ the loop instead of before the loop.

Comment: Well you have a while on error (== 1).  Neither 'm' or 'f' give an error so it breaks out of while.  I don't know what 'resets' means here.  It should hit the confirm bit on 'm' or 'f' and keep asking otherwise.  Personally as user I would be annoyed to be asked to confirm my gender.

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error for `if (not(GenderSelect.lower() == "f" GenderSelect.lower() == "m")):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your this part of code :

```
if (GenderSelect.lower() == "f"):
    print("Name: " + NameCreate + "\nAge: " + str(AgeSelect) + "\nGender: Female\n")
    gerror = 0
if (not(GenderSelect.lower() == "f" GenderSelect.lower() == "m")):
    gerror = 1
```

should be :

```
elif (GenderSelect.lower() == "f"):
    print("Name: " + NameCreate + "\nAge: " + str(AgeSelect) + "\nGender: Female\n")
    gerror = 0
else:
    gerror = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems:

1. Use `elif` instead of `if` for things that are mutually exclusive
2. In your final if statement within your `gerror` block, you need an `or` between the two conditions. Or just use `else`.